# How to sort list of strings (containing numbers) in an ascending order

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I know this is a very basic question but from the answers I saw while searching I didn't find something good enough for this one.

I have the following names of files I received while using `mylist = os.listdir(<folder_path>)`:

```
['file.0', 'file.1', 'file.10', 'file.100', 'file.2', 'file.3']
```

I want sort this list in an ascending order like that:

```
['file.0', 'file.1', 'file.2', 'file.3', 'file.10', 'file.100']
```

I tried to use `mylist.sort()` but it it leaves the list without any changes. The `sorted()` function also doesn't do any change.

One workaround is to separate the numbers from the strings and cast them to integers to a new array:

```
[0, 1, 10, 100, 2, 3]
```

And then sort them:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 100]
```

Then I need a function to do `"file." + i`.

But is there a better way to do it ?

I noticed that Windows does it and I think they are doing it with some sting sorting:
[image]

Comment: It should be pointed out that it _is_ actually sorting it, however since they are strings `file.10` comes before `file.2` because `1` is less then `2` (the `0` is irrelevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `split('.')`, which splits your elements of your list where it finds `.`. If you then cast the last element to `int`, you can use that as a key to sort on:

```
sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: int(x.split('.')[-1]))
```

Returns:

```
['file.0', 'file.1', 'file.2', 'file.3', 'file.10', 'file.100']
```